# Installing featuretools library in google datalab gives error

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-datalab, featuretools

I am trying to install featuretools library in Google datalabs. Tried with few versions but still it is giving error of incompatibility.
Also tried in python 2 and python 3 both.

```
!pip install -I featuretools==0.5.1
```

[image]

Tried 0.6.1, 0.6.0 and 0.5.1 but nothing worked.

Comment: These are errors of incompatibility. Some of your packages have incompatible dependencies. However, from the screenshot, it looks like featuretools 0.5.1 was installed. `import featuretools as ft` it should work. If this is an error with featuretools, feel free to post an issue on [github](https://github.com/Featuretools/featuretools/issues)

Comment: Same command when I run on my laptop it works fine. And I am able to import featuretools. However datalab may have some pre installed packages which are incompatible and hence it is not allowing me to install on datalab. I don't think it is package issue. It has something to do with google datalab.